# erros with dictionary keys and values conversion in python

Tags: python

I am writing a code for Egyptian division in python. 
what is Egyptian division
For example,  17 divided by 3.

```
    Powers of two column        divisor doubling column

        2^0 = 1                       3
        2^1 = 2                       6
        2^2 = 4                      12
        2^3 = 8                      24
    24>17 so we can stop.
```

Looking at the combinations of 3, 6, and 12 we see that 12 + 3 = 15 is 
the closest we can seem to get without going over 17.

Now I got the above output but i couldn't get the quotient as i am using dictionary and it gives me an error.

```
 import sys
astring = raw_input("Enter the A integer: ")   #accepting input
a = int(astring)                               #dividend 
bstring = raw_input("Enter the B integer: ")   # accepting input
b = int(bstring)                               #divisor 
Egyptian_Division_dict = {}                    # initiating dictionary 
i =0                                           # setting counter for 2^i
x =0
z =0
#k = 0  #m = 0
list_of_divisor = []
list_of_two = []
while i< a:
    k = 2**i
    m =  k*b
    if  m < a:
        list_of_divisor.append (k)
        list_of_two.append(m)
    i += 1
for i in range(len(list_of_divisor)):
    Egyptian_Division_dict[list_of_divisor[i]] = list_of_two[i]
list_of_divisor = sorted(list_of_divisor, reverse=True)
list_of_two = sorted(list_of_two, reverse=True)
print "printing dictionary" 
for keys,values in sorted (Egyptian_Division_dict.items(),reverse = True):
    print (keys), (values)
    #if z == a:
       # z=+value
        #print z
rough = 0
quetient = 0
for keys in sorted (Egyptian_Division_dict.items(),reverse = True):
    #Egyptian_Division_dict[keys] = str([keys])
    #Egyptian_Division_dict[values] = str([values])
    w = keys 
    z = values
    if rough + z <a:
        rough = rough+z
        quetient = quetient + w
    else :
        print quetient
```

error:

```
Enter the A integer: 44                                                                                                                                             
Enter the B integer: 4                                                                                                                                              
printing dictionary                                                                                                                                                 
8 32                                                                                                                                                                
4 16                                                                                                                                                                
2 8                                                                                                                                                                 
1 4                                                                                                                                                                 
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                  
  File "main.py", line 39, in <module>                                                                                                                              
    quetient = quetient + w                                                                                                                                         
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'tuple'
```

How can I remove this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second loop, you are assigning the `(key, value)` tuple to a single variable, `keys`:

```
for keys in sorted (Egyptian_Division_dict.items(),reverse = True):
```

You then try to add that tuple to an integer:

```
quetient = 0

# in the loop
w = keys 
quetient = quetient + w
```

It is that last line that throws the exception.

You appear to have forgotten to include a `values` variable in that loop; adding it back in would at least make `keys` be a single key again:

```
for keys, values in sorted (Egyptian_Division_dict.items(),reverse = True):
```

With that change, the value for `quetient` is indeed added up to 15:

```
>>> Egyptian_Division_dict = {8: 32, 4: 16, 2: 8, 1: 4}
>>> rough = 0
>>> quetient = 0
>>> for keys, values in sorted (Egyptian_Division_dict.items(),reverse = True):
...     w = keys
...     z = values
...     if rough + z <a:
...         rough = rough+z
...         quetient = quetient + w
...     else :
...         print quetient
...
>>> quetient
15
```

Comment: oh thank you very much. error is removed and my code is working smoothly .